# Multiple version of pod file showing in project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github, gitlab

We are working more than 10 developers on same project and using **gitlab**. So we are committing and merging code. We are facing a problem that in pod file list I can see same pod file with different version number

[image: Please view Image]

Mean while there are multiple code files are in directory.

[image]

> > Someone have an idea whats its happening and what is the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just use gitignore on the `Pods/`. So no one can push any changes from their pods.

Comment: what about multiple files ?

Comment: I am sensing this is a bad workflow that happened on your team. My suggestion would be, you need to fix your main branch first. Remove unnecessary code/library, then update the .gitignore. Finally, everyone need to clone that main branch and follow the same procedure. No one can't push unless they use the same base branch.